# ccache with MingW on Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, windows-xp, ccache

I am trying to use ccache however I get this error when I try to compile my project:

> ccache: FATAL: Unable to determine
>   cache directory

I download the file from [here](http://ccache-win32.googlecode.com/files/ccache-win32-2.4.zip), How can I know the appropriate directory that ccache use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem with [ccache version](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~kendy/ccache/ccache.exe) witch is depend in [cygwin1.dll](http://ifile.it/g57nsyo), I put them in bin directory under Mingw directory and now every thing work as expected.